# i can not deal with my if statement

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

i made my first Workflow using SPD 2010 but it doesn't work correctly . my issue is to automate vacations cycle in my organization. First ask the person about vacation type and his alternate person's account and an his manager account and then ask the alternate person about whether it was OK or not and if it is not OK i have to stop the work flow. how can i?

Answer (score 0):

Having a hard time understanding your issue. Check out the Approval Workflow that's already in SharePoint. That sounds like what you need.

Comment: but i want to learn how to deal with if statement and understand variables types of the spd 2010 through this workflow .can you help me ?

Comment: Check out this video for assistance, great walkthrough: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/video-create-an-approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-VA101897477.aspx